# How to make Accordion menu close when clicked again

Tags: css

I built a simple Accordion menu base on HTML and CSS only. The functionality is good, but the problem is when you click an open accordion it won't close.

Can I do that with CSS or do I need JavaScript?

```css
.middle a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #2980b9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #3498db;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.smenu {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.smenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.smenu a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item:target .smenu {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="menu">
    <li class="item" id="aboutus">
      <a href="#aboutus" class="btn">About Us</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="contactus">
      <a href="#contactus" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>000-000-000</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>Send Us An Email</a>
        <a>ABCDEFG</a>
        <a>P.O> Box 00000</a>
        <a>New York, New York 000000</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Monday - Friday: 9AM - 5PM ET</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>Saturday-Sunday: Closed</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>Online: 24/7</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="sitelinks">
      <a href="#sitelinks" class="btn">Site Links</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4t</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
      </div>
    </li>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jhon and welcome to SO. You could close your accordion on `:hover` but not on click if you intend on using only CSS (unless you set a complex html target system). You'll need JS if you want better and more functionnality. Have you noticed that your accordion closes if you click on a link within it right now ?

Comment: Yes, it closes when it clicks some links, and also it will close when you click on other panels. [link](https://codepen.io/jhongeric-pescador/pen/GLMqPq)

Comment: I think you can't do it using CSS only, you can use a simple javascript to do this so, if you don't want to use javascript you can use :hover instead of :target

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

Opening one of your accordion panels is based on that panel `li class="item"` being the current *target* (hash)

```
.item:target .smenu {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

The only way to close that panel, then, is for the `<li>` to no longer be the target, and clicking the item again will not do that; you'll have to click something else, or resort to javascript — so the basic answer to *"Can I do that with CSS or do I need JavaScript?"* is that you'll need javascript.

### Javascript Does It

The good news is that it's a pretty simple piece of javascript. Here it is, wrapped in a `DOMContentLoaded` as you would need to do if it is in its own .js file that is linked from the page:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li.item');
    for (let item of items) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                if ('#'+e.currentTarget.id === location.hash) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.location.hash = '';
                }
        });
    }
});
```

### What does it do?

This queries (querySelectorAll) for all of the menu items; the `li.item`s that are within the `.menu`
It then loops over each of those and attaches an event listener for the "click" event. That's it.

The event listener itself is also simple. It uses the event `e` and gets the `id` of the current target of the click, if that is the same as the current location.hash that means you're clicking on what is already open, so... prevent the default action (navigating to the hash again), and clear the hash.

Now with the hash cleared, the `.item:target` CSS selector doesn't match anything so the previously open accordion pane closes.

### As a Stack Snippet

When we make a snippet, the snippet takes care of waiting for the DOM to be ready, so we'll take that wrapper off. Here it is, all I have done is add some Javascript to your own snippet:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li.item');
    for (let item of items) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                                if ('#'+e.currentTarget.id === location.hash) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    window.location.hash = '';
                                }
        });
    }
```

```css
.middle a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #2980b9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #3498db;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px
}

.smenu {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.smenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.smenu a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item:target .smenu {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="menu">
    <li class="item" id="aboutus">
      <a href="#aboutus" class="btn">About Us</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="contactus">
      <a href="#contactus" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>000-000-000</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>Send Us An Email</a>
        <a>ABCDEFG</a>
        <a>P.O> Box 00000</a>
        <a>New York, New York 000000</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Monday - Friday: 9AM - 5PM ET</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>Saturday-Sunday: Closed</a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>Online: 24/7</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="sitelinks">
      <a href="#sitelinks" class="btn">Site Links</a>
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4t</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
      </div>
    </li>


  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, since you don't need the `items` for anything except looping, you don't even have to assign them to a variable.
Here is a further minimized version that replaces the explicit functions with arrow functions.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.menu li.item')
            .forEach(element =>
                  element.addEventListener('click',
                     e => {
                            if ('#'+e.currentTarget.id === location.hash) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                window.location.hash = '';
                            }
                          })
                 )
});
```

The `if ('#'+e.currentTarget.id === ...` could probably also be turned into a predicate, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great and extensive answer ! In your opinion, for this kind of behavior, don't you think using a simple class toggle would be easier ?

Comment: @Jake actually I first started my answer that way, and started changing the CSS to use a class in place of `:target`, then realized I didn't have to change any of the OP's styles or markup because changing the hash would do it. I haven't checked, but I think changing the hash will become part of the browser history too, so the back button will work.

Comment: I was simply wondering if toggling a class or something along those lines wouldn't be much simpler and take fewer lines of codes to achieve the same

Comment: @Jake - I think it would be simpler, at least for comprehension, and I would probably approach the problem by using classes myself. Maybe I'll add another example using that approach.